# How to organize a complex Apache Flink application?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We use flink to generate events from some IoT sensors. each sensor can be used to generate different kinds of events ( like temp, humidity, etc ). One to many ratio (sensor -> enabled events).
Mapping between sensors and enabled events stored in relation database

In order to enrich sensors data, we gonna connect sensors datastream and table API. Just adding metadata with a list of enabled events.

So, if some specific `sensor-123` has enabled events only `TEMP` and `PRESSURE`, how to send sensor data only to these two defined process functions?

something like the following comes to mind:

```
val enriched: DataStream[EnrichedSensorData] = ...

val temp = enriched.filter(x => isTempEnabled(x)).process(....)
val humd = enriched.filter(x => isHumdEnabled(x)).process(....)
val press = enriched.filter(x => isPressEnabled(x)).process(....)
```

1. how effective is it? how best to do in terms of flink best practices?
   as I understand it, in my case I multiply the data stream several times, even though I then filter the result
2. What is the best way to do the data enrichment process in my case?
   connect sensor data stream with table stream ( via flink-cdc-connector) + use state in enrichment process function to cache mapping sensorId -> List(enabledEvents)?

[image: architecture]

Answer (score 1):

1. Use side outputs from the enrichment function to generate the three streams of events. If you have a performance issue that seems related to replicating the data, you could try pipelining it (have the TEMP, HUMIDITY and PRESSURE functions inline, and just forward any record that isn't appropriate to process).
2. If you have millions of sensors, each with metadata, then use a JDBC source, and do a (stateful) join with the sensor data. You'd have to handle the case of getting a sensor data record before the corresponding metadata record, in which case you'd want to store it in state, and then generate the result (and clear state) when the metadata record arrives.

Comment: the number of sensors metadata is equal to the number of sensors of which there are millions

Comment: actually all the event computation functions goes to the same sink
updated a diagram in original post